# How to Increase and decrease height of a flex layout with a animation xamarin forms

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I am trying to do some thing like expand and collapse with a animation using flex layout.

but i am not sure how i use animation with the change of height.

my Xamal code like below.

```
<ScrollView>
        <StackLayout>
        <FlexLayout BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding SampleCollection}" 
           Wrap="Wrap"
           Direction="Row"
           JustifyContent="Start"
           AlignItems="Start"
           AlignContent="Start"
           Padding="8">
            <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid Margin="4,4,4,4"
                      FlexLayout.Basis="{OnIdiom Phone='50%'}"
                      FlexLayout.AlignSelf="Start"
                          >

                        <Frame
                            WidthRequest="30"
                            HeightRequest="30">
                            <Label Text="{Binding}"/>
                        </Frame>


                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
        </FlexLayout>

            <Button HorizontalOptions="Center" Text="More" Command="{Binding ClickedCommand}"/>

        </StackLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```

my viewmodel like below.

```
public class SampleFlexViewModel
    {
        private bool isExpand;
        public SampleFlexViewModel()
        {
            var list = new List<string>();
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                list.Add($"Test {i}");
            }

            SampleCollection = list.Take(6).ToObservableCollection();

            ClickedCommand = new Command(() => 
            {
                SampleCollection.Clear();

                if (isExpand)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < list.Take(6).ToList().Count; i++)
                    {
                        SampleCollection.Add(list[i]);

                    }
                    isExpand = !isExpand;
                }

                else
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
                    {
                        SampleCollection.Add(list[i]);

                    }
                    isExpand = !isExpand;
                }
            });
        }

        public ICommand ClickedCommand { set; get; }

        public ObservableCollection<string> SampleCollection { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<string>();
    }
```

basically in first time i need to display 6 items.

when i click the button it should display the rest of items.

is there any other way to do this?

because i see iterating two for loops might be costly.

and how can i add a animation there?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use change ItemSource count to implement expand and collapse with a animation， I suggest you can LayoutTo function  to do this.

```
  <StackLayout x:Name="stacklayout1">
        <Button
            Command="{Binding ClickedCommand}"
            HorizontalOptions="Center"
            Text="More" />

        <FlexLayout
            x:Name="flexlayout1"
            Padding="8"
            AlignContent="Start"
            AlignItems="Start"
            BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding SampleCollection}"
            Direction="Row"
            JustifyContent="Start"
            Wrap="Wrap">
            <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid
                        Margin="4,4,4,4"
                        FlexLayout.AlignSelf="Start"
                        FlexLayout.Basis="{OnIdiom Phone='50%'}">

                        <Frame HeightRequest="30" WidthRequest="30">
                            <Label Text="{Binding}" />
                        </Frame>


                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
        </FlexLayout>
    </StackLayout>

 public partial class Page9 : ContentPage
{
    public ObservableCollection<string> SampleCollection { get; set; }
    public Command ClickedCommand { get; set; }
    private bool isexpand=true;
    public Page9()
    {
        InitializeComponent();       
        SampleCollection = new ObservableCollection<string>();

        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            SampleCollection.Add("Test is " + i);
        }
        ClickedCommand = new Command(() =>
        {
            if(isexpand)
            {
                stacklayout1.LayoutTo(new Rectangle(stacklayout1.Bounds.X, stacklayout1.Bounds.Y, stacklayout1.Bounds.Width, 300), 500, Easing.CubicIn);
                isexpand = false;
            }
            else
            {
                stacklayout1.LayoutTo(new Rectangle(stacklayout1.Bounds.X, stacklayout1.Bounds.Y, stacklayout1.Bounds.Width, flexlayout1.Bounds.Height+40), 500, Easing.CubicOut);
                isexpand = false;
            }              
        });

        this.BindingContext = this;

    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: This is really good example,  can I do this without adding fix sizes for flex layout height.

Comment: @ChanduRanwala For layout, it may need to one fix sizes to increase and decrease stacklayout height.